# Variable not being passed from front end to backend

Tags: javascript, api

I'm scratching my head at this problem, I'm implementing Instagrams basic display API using Wix's new editor-x. My code works if I run it on the client side, I get an access token, however it doesn't when I import the getAccessToken function from the server side, the function runs but I get an invalid auth code.

I think there maybe an issue passing the code variable?

frontend code:

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location'
import {getAccessToken} from 'backend/instagram'
let query = wixLocation.query; //get auth code from URL param
    let code = query.code
    console.log(code) //check code is correct
    if(code){
        const token = await getAccessToken(code) //request accesstoken
        console.log(token) //log token
        }
```

backend code:

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch'
export async function getAccessToken(code) {
    const url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: `client_id=id&client_secret=secret&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=uri&code=${code}`
    }
    try {
        const data = await fetch(url,options)
        const token = await data.json()
        return token
    } catch(error) {
        return error
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the imports in the front end code are actually importing something?

Comment: what is your frontend code without backend import?

Comment: @Teemu yes the imports are working as it will log the token in the console

Comment: @ikhvjs if i move the contents of the function getAccessToken from backend to frontend it works fine. hope that helps.

Comment: @jahkoora, are your using nodejs? nodejs doesn't have builtin `fetch()` api, you may install axios or node-fetch.

Comment: @ikhvjs im using fetch from wix-fetch, you think this is the issue? As I said if I do the fetch on the frontend it works...

Comment: @jahkoora, yes. I think you need to install [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). The [documentation](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-fetch/introduction) mention it: `The implementation of the Fetch API differs slightly depending on where it's being used. The features documented here comprise the base functionality for both implementations. However, each implementation contains additional features:

In public files, the native browser's Fetch API is used.
In backend files the node-fetch module is used.`

Comment: @ikhvjs looks like node-fetch is already installed, wix will call node-fetch when using wix-fetch in backend files automatically. 

OK I just tested the code using a setTimeout() on the front end, and its returning me the accesstoken - I think the issue is that it was running more than once on load somehow and the Instagram api was responding that it already used that code.